# What is meant by 'frame' in this for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
for group, frame in Top15.groupby(ContinentDict):
    groups.loc[group] = [len(frame), frame['Estimate Population'].sum(),frame['Estimate Population'].mean(),frame['Estimate Population'].std()]
```

I understand the for-loop acts on each group, but what is a frame? Is that a row? Column? Value? I guess dataFrame, but how is there more than one frame if the loop is only acting on the dataFrame Top15?

Comment: Try using `print(frame)` and see what happens :)

Comment: There is a section in the [`groupby` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups) that addresses your question exactly.  You get a separate `frame` to work with for each level in your grouping.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say I load the below data in df.

```
continent   count
0   Asia    1
1   Asia    1
2   Asia    1
10  Europe  1
11  Europe  1

for i,j in df[['continent','count']].groupby('continent'):
    print(i,j.shape)
```

Result of above query would be

```
Asia  (3,2)
Europe (2,2)
```

j is a slice of df where

```
j = df.loc[df['continent'] == 'Asia',:] with index as 'continent'
```

respectively